# How merge/mix range of cell as formula parameter

Tags: excel, merge, range

In Excel I want to calculate XIRR of a projects.
My payments are in two separate ranges.
But XIRR function (and other) accept single range as parameter.
How Can I merge ranges in functions parameters?
Like something as this

```
=XIRR(MixRanges(a1:a4,d1:d2), MixRanges(b1:b4,e1:e2))
```

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was trying not to use a UDF, but I couldn't figure out a clever built-in function to use.

Add this code to your workbook:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function MergeRange(ParamArray rng()) As Single()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim count As Long
    Dim r As Excel.Range
    Dim s() As Single

    For i = LBound(rng) To UBound(rng)
        If (TypeOf rng(i) Is Excel.Range) Then
            For Each r In rng(i)
                ReDim Preserve s(count)
                s(count) = r.Value

                count = count + 1
            Next r
        End If
    Next i

    MergeRange = s
End Function
```

And use it like so:

`=XIRR(MergeRange(A2:A6,D2:D6),MergeRange(B2:B6,E2:E6),0.1)`

This will accept multiple ranges, grab their values, and return the values as a contiguous array. Since XIRR needs values and dates, using the `Single` data type should be ok.

Comment: This function works great in Windows but not in mac os. Does someone know what could be the issue?

Comment: @mend what about it isn't working for you? I just tried it on a Mac and it looks like it's working ok (Excel version 16.15).

Answer (score 1):

For your specific example you can use `CHOOSE`, i.e.

`=XIRR(CHOOSE({1,2,3,4,5,6},A1,A2,A3,A4,D1,D2),CHOOSE({1,2,3,4,5,6},B1,B2,B3,B4,E1,E2))`

but that might not be easy to extend for larger ranges......

Comment: +1 for making use of Choose() :) I almost never find a way to use it

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the XIRR, but I was trying to do the same with `RANK.EQ` and I found that all that is needed are brackets i.e. `=RANK.EQ(J6,(J$6:$J$999,S$6:$S$999),0)`.