# VBA function works in windows but not in mac os

Tags: excel, vba, macos

This VBA function for merging range works in windows but gives `#VALUE` in mac os.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function MergeRange(ParamArray rng()) As Single()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim count As Long
    Dim r As Excel.Range
    Dim s() As Single

    For i = LBound(rng) To UBound(rng)
        If (TypeOf rng(i) Is Excel.Range) Then
            For Each r In rng(i)
                ReDim Preserve s(count)
                s(count) = r.Value

                count = count + 1
            Next r
        End If
    Next i

    MergeRange = s
End Function
```

The code comes from another stackoverflow thread [How merge/mix range of cell as formula parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19248509/how-merge-mix-range-of-cell-as-formula-parameter)

Comment: Well, give us a clue - which line has the value error?

Comment: Can you show the code how you use this function? A [mcve] might help here.

Comment: Maybe `Dim r As Range`?

Comment: Call the function from a Sub instead of from a worksheet cell and you'll be able to debug it.

Comment: Works fine for me in Excel 2016 on Mac, assuming none of the inputs are an error. What version are you using?

Comment: My version: Excel 2016 15.21.1. Tried creating a workbook from scratch but still the same error.